# Plotting multiple variables in one boxplot

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 4*10 datasheet like so:

```
Total, var1, var2, var3 
104, 35, 33, 36
106, 38, 32, 36
93, 34, 27, 32
98, 31, 32, 35
101, 34, 32, 35
106, 38, 32, 36
82, 32, 23, 27
100, 38, 30, 32
111, 34, 39, 38
89, 35, 27, 27
```

and I would like to produce a `boxplot` where each column is plotted as a separate boxplot but on the same graph. Ideally I would also like to colour code these and add some `jitter` to show the individual data points.

So far I have tried to use the melt functionality on `reshape2` but I haven't had much luck.

I hope this is clear, it's been giving me lots of headaches. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data like this:

```
> head(data)
  Total var1 var2 var3
1   104   35   33   36
2   106   38   32   36
3    93   34   27   32
4    98   31   32   35
5   101   34   32   35
6   106   38   32   36
```

then this bit of `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(reshape2::melt(data), aes(x=variable, y=value, col=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(height=0,col="black")
```

gets you:

[image]

I don't see the point of colouring things when the position and the axis label is sufficient, but whatever. Also, if you colour the points by variable as well you lose them against the boxplot so I kept them black.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that the colouring seems a little pointless here but it's to keep this plot similar to others I have.